# How to dynamically position a page element at the top left of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement an html table which allows editing of data in a cell by positioning an input control over it when the cell receives focus and setting its value to the value of the cell.  When the input control loses focus, its value is put into the cell being edited and the input control is hidden.

The code looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

```
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="border:1px solid black;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>This is line 1</td>
                <td id="cell1" class="editable" contenteditable="true" stye="width:100px;text-align:right;">1234567</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>This is line 2</td>
                <td id="cell2" class="editable" contenteditable="true" stye="width:100px;text-align:right;">98765</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input id="editor" data-cellid="#cell1" type="number" style="text-align:right;" value="">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(".editable").on("focus", function () {
            $("#editor").val($(this).text());
            $("#editor").data("cellid", "#" + $(this).attr("id"));
            $("#editor").height($(this).height());
            $("#editor").width($(this).width() + 20);
            var pos = $(this).offset();
            $("#editor").offset({top: pos.top, left: pos.left});
            $("#editor").show();
            $("#editor").focus();
        })

        $("#editor").on("blur", function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            var id = $(this).data("cellid");
            $(id).text(value);
            $(this).hide();
        })</script>

</body>
```

The first time I click one of the editable cells, the input control is correctly positioned.  On the second and subsequent clicks on any of the editable cells, the input control appears one line further down the screen than its last position and also further over to the right.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I run your code, the input control appears correctly for me (Google Chrome v64.0.3282.167 (official build) (64 bits))

Comment: Better to use inputs or editable divs here, keep it simple

Comment: When you run the code snippet, the jquery isn't executed since it's in a separate file on my server so all you see is the effect of contenteditable="true".  I'll edit the code so it's inline with the html.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that .position has no effect on hidden elements.  I removed the $(this).hide() line and now the editor is positioned correctly.  I have to show #editor before setting its position but that doesn't cause any visual weirdness.